# About two functions being same or noy

Tags: integration, functions

I wanted to ask if two functions f and g of two variables x and t , integrated with respect to t on a common interval from a to b are the same for all x ,can we say the integrands are the same?

Comment: In other words, you are asking if we can say that $f(x,t) = g(x,t)$ over $t \in [a,b]$ if for all $x$ we have $\int_a^b f(x,t) dt = \int_a^b g(x,t) dt$?

Comment: Yes , thats exactly that

Comment: Would this be true if $f,g$ do not depend on $x$? So if you are in a regular one-variable case?

Comment: Well i know the function depends on x , actually it is a integral defined function thats why parameter t is required

Comment: I can't say ,but let me be more clear. We now that integral t to the x dt from 0 to 1 gives $1/(1+x)$ and we can taylor expand this and we can write each term of the series as some integral from 0 to 1 so would those integrands be the same?

Comment: No, take $f(x,t)=0$ and $g(x,0) =1$ and $g(x,t)=0$ for $t\ne 0$, then $\int_0^1 f(x,t) \,dt = \int_0^1 g(x,t) \,dt $ for all $x$, but $f(x,0)\ne g(x,0)$

Comment: Well ,lets say the function is not piecewise as this but a continuous ,"nice" one ,how about that case?

Comment: For the one-variable case, just because $\int_{-1}^1 t dt = 0 = \int_{-1}^1 t^3 dt$, that does not mean that $t = t^3$... Even if you assume $f,g \ge 0$, we can still end up with $x+10$ and $x^3+10$ over the same $[-1,1]$ with the same results...

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting conversation would be if you assume $\int_a^T (f(t)-g(t))dt = 0$ for all $T \in (a,b]$.